# Error connecting adb on Android Things

Tags: android, adb, intel-edison, android-things

I have a Intel Edison running Android Things.  I was able to adb fine into the device using usb.  I wanted to switch to using adb over tcp/ip.  So I ran the following command.

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb kill-server
```

I then disconnected my device from the usb cable and rebooted it.  When I try to connect to my device via:

```
adb connect 10.0.0.20
```

I get the following error:

```
unable to connect to 10.0.0.20:5555: Connection refused
```

I do see the device on the network, just that I am not able to connect to it.  When I connect the device via usb again, I am unable to connect via usb either since it doesn't show up in the adb device list.

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
<no devices listed>
```

Two questions:

1. How can I flip the device back to being debuggable via USB?
2. How do I correctly setup adb over tcp/ip?

Comment: @Onik adb doesn't find any devices 'adb usb
error: no devices/emulators found'. Has it somehow persisted the request to listen on tcp?

Comment: @Onik, no - I get the connection refused error.

Comment: Did that - no effect.  Usb is the power supply in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the help in any case!  Reboot of the host fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like rebooting my host machine fixed it (MB Pro).  Likely an issue with the USB stack - connecting/disconnecting the device so often most likely caused some weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reboot the machine host.
After reboot, do the connection again : `adb connect <ip_address>:5555`